# Right Shift and Left shift operator in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, operator-keyword

How to use Right Shift operator in classic ASP. As suggested in  [In ASP, Bit Operator Left shift and Right shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466413/in-asp-bit-operator-left-shift-and-right-shift) , I used "\" for right shift operator. it gives me wrong result.

For example
in javascript, 33555758 >> 24 gives result 2.
But in Classic ASP 33555758 \ 24 gives division result.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise right shift `>>` is not equal to simple division `\` by the given number, but by the given number of times by integer 2, which is binary 10. A bit shift moves each digit in a set of bits right. I.e. dividing by binary 10 removes a binary digit from the number and shifts digits right.

Example: 5 >> 1 = 2

```
5       00000000000000000000000000000101 
5 >> 1  00000000000000000000000000000010 (2)
```

which is same as 5 / 2,

i.e. in your case it will be not `33555758 \ 24` but 24 times dividing 2. As there is no direct method in vbscript, it can be done as

```
Function SignedRightShift(pValue, pShift)

Dim NewValue, PrevValue, i
PrevValue = pValue
For i = 1 to pShift
    Select Case VarType(pValue)
        Case vbLong
            NewValue = Int((PrevValue And "&H7FFFFFFF") / 2)
            If PrevValue And "&H80000000" Then NewValue = NewValue Or "&HC0000000"
            NewValue = CLng(NewValue)
        Case vbInteger
            NewValue = Int((PrevValue And "&H7FFF") / 2)
            If PrevValue And "&H8000" Then NewValue = NewValue Or "&HC000"
            NewValue = CInt("&H"+ Hex(NewValue))
        Case vbByte
            NewValue = Int(PrevValue / 2)
            If PrevValue And "&H80" Then NewValue = NewValue Or "&HC0"
            NewValue = CByte(NewValue)
        Case Else: Err.Raise 13 ' Not a supported type
    End Select
    PrevValue = NewValue
Next
SignedRightShift = PrevValue

End Function
```

and used as

```
x = SignedRightShift(33555758, 24)
```

For more, see http://chris.wastedhalo.com/2014/05/more-binarybitwise-functions-for-vbscript/